# POST form route has POST route in address bar

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post

I am using node + express. I currently have a text input in a form where when you submit it searches for users in a mongo DB with the given search term. However, whenever I perform a search, the URL changes to "localhost:8080/searchGlobalUsers" when it should be "localhost:8080/talk". Here is my post route:

```
app.post('/searchGlobalUsers', function(req, res){
    var regex = new RegExp(req.body.globalUserSearch, 'i');
    console.log("GLOBAL_USER_SEARCH: " + req.body.globalUserSearch);
    User.find({username: regex}, function(err, globalUserSearchQuery){
        res.render("talk", {globalUserSearchQuery : globalUserSearchQuery});
    });
});
```

And here is my text input + form

```
   <form action="/searchGlobalUsers" method="POST" >
         <div class="row">
              <input type="text" name="globalUserSearch" class="u-full-width" placeholder="Search" id="add-friend-search-input">
         </div>
         <div class="row">
              <button class="button-green-large" class="u-full-width" id="add-friend-search-submit">Search</button>
         </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: you are redirecting your page to /searchGlobalUsers that why your url is like localhost:8080/searchGlobalUsers and in searchGlobalUsers route you are rendering the talk view

Answer (score 0):

render function is use to provide view to the client
just use this code

```
    app.post('/searchGlobalUsers', function(req, res){
        var regex = new RegExp(req.body.globalUserSearch, 'i');
        console.log("GLOBAL_USER_SEARCH: " + req.body.globalUserSearch);
        User.find({username: regex}, function(err, globalUserSearchQuery){
            req.flash('info', globalUserSearchQuery);            
           return res.redirect("/talk");
        });
    });

   app.get('/talk', function(req, res){
     res.render("talk", {"globalUserSearchQuery" : req.flash('info')});
   })
```